# Enterprise Data Application Block, Stored Procedures and parameters with default values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

We have an ASP.NET 2.0 application that uses Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block heavily. There is a helper routine which in short accepts an array of parameters for a SP along with the name of the SP and calls that SP. So effectively

```
  object[] parameters = string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsString) ? null : jss.Deserialize<object[]>(paramsString);

DbCommand procProcess = Database.GetStoredProcCommand(_storedProc, parameters);
```

We also have a lot of stored procedures that rely on default values for parameters. Usually these parameters with default values are always at the end of stored proc definition such as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
@param1 int
,@param2 int
,@param3 int = 0
AS
....
```

I want to be able to call the proc by passing in the values for just param1 and param2. But ofcourse if my parameters has only two params, then this call

```
DbCommand procProcess = Database.GetStoredProcCommand(_storedProc, parameters);
```

would still bring back param3 but will not assign it its default value. Hence the call

```
 procProcess.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

will fail.

Can anyone help me in either omitting these parameters with default values specified or pass them the SQL equivalent of keyword "default" somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself. Basically I refactored the code to accept either an object array of parameters which then gets passed to the

```
DbCommand procProcess = Database.GetStoredProcCommand(_storedProc, parameters);
```

call or accept a serialized representation of array of a custom class which simply lists param names and their values. The code then deserializes this passed in array of the custom class and does something like

```
DbCommand procProcess = Database.GetStoredProcCommand(_storedProc);

                    for (int i = 0; i < typedparams.Length; i++)
                        procProcess.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(typedparams[i].ParamName.StartsWith("\\@") ? typedparams[i].ParamName : "@" + typedparams[i].ParamName, typedparams[i].ParamValue));
```